# How can I plot specific points on top of another line plot?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, matplotlib, plot

I'm a trader and I want to keep track of all my position entry points along the underlying securitie's price movement. For instance here is the code I have for my BTC position so far. I import my libraries, load my data and I plot the range of the last few months of closing price data. Everything is just how I want it, but I can't figure out how to plot my position entries.

Here is the code and output:

```
# Libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import yfinance as yf


# Data load
BTC = yf.download(tickers='BTC-USD', start='2020-10-01', end='2021-05-03')
BTC_close = BTC['Close']
print(BTC.head())
BTC_positions = yf.download(tickers='BTC-USD', start='2021-02-01', end='2021-05-03')
MyBTC = BTC_positions['Close']
df_RAW = pd.DataFrame(BTC_positions, columns=['Date','Close'])



# Plot
fig = plt.figure()
f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.tick_params(length=3, direction='in', labelsize=10)
fmt = '${x:,.0f}'
tick = mtick.StrMethodFormatter(fmt)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tick)
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(direction='in')
MyBTC.plot(figsize=(12, 7))
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
plt.title("Bitcoin Position Entries", fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Day',fontsize=13) # or fontsize=10
plt.ylabel('Price $$$',fontsize=13) # or fontsize=10
plt.show()
```

Output plot:
Raw  data plot that I want to plot my entries on
[image: Raw data plot]

I've tried incorporating 2 different dictionaries:

Dictionary 1 with key:value pairs of date-of-entry:amount-of-money-spent

```
Dict1 = {
    '2021-02-17': 250,
    '2021-02-24': 250,
    '2021-02-28': 50,
    '2021-03-08': 500,
    '2021-04-10': 500,
    '2021-04-14': 120,
    '2021-04-17': 400,
    '2021-04-21': 120,
    '2021-04-22': 875,
    '2021-04-23': 300,
    '2021-04-29': 125
}
```

Dictionary 2 with key:value pairs of date-of-entry:price-of-underlying-security

```
Dict2 = {
    'Date': ['2021-02-17','2021-02-24','2021-02-28','2021-03-08','2021-04-10','2021-04-14','2021-04-17','2021-04-21','2021-04-22','2021-04-23','2021-04-29'],
    'Price': [51280, 49426, 44548, 50840, 60251, 62479, 53637, 55946, 51376, 48080, 53955]
}
```

The problem I'm facing is I purchased $250 worth on Feb.17 but I want that dot to show up at the appropriate price of entry, which was $51,280, so the y-axis is out of scale.
I was thinking I could plot the dots and just vary their size or color gradient based on amount purchased (smaller purchase = small/light dot, bigger purchase = big/dark dot)

I tried creating a DataFrame because I thought this would make it easier but I have just confused myself even further.

I have gotten this far and have absolutely no idea how to go about it. I thought I was on the right track utilizing Dict1 and Dict2 but I feel more confused now. Any help at all on how to go about this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the `Dict1.items()` to get the `date` and the `Close` price from the `MyBTC` dataframe (you can also use [`annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html) to add the price you bought from `Dict1`). Then, apply the [`scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) function to plot specific points on top of the already existing line plot. This function place the markers at the location given by `date` in the x-axis and the close price (`closep` from `MyBTC`) in the y-axis, and, as usual for some matplotlib, you can set the marker shape, size (`linewidths`) and color.

```py
...
...
plt.xlabel('Day',fontsize=13) # or fontsize=10
plt.ylabel('Price $$$',fontsize=13) # or fontsize=10

for date,buy_price  in Dict1.items():
    closep = MyBTC[date]
    plt.annotate(str(buy_price), (date, closep), xytext=(-3, 6),
            textcoords='offset points',  weight='bold', fontsize=12)
    plt.scatter(date, closep, marker='v', linewidths=1, color='r')

plt.show()
```

[image: plot_with_markers]